# Found Unit: Required [SomethingElse]

Tags: scala, type-mismatch

I have the following scala function and I it won't compile because it finds Unit even tough it requires [SomethingElse]

```
def combine(trees: List[CodeTree]): List[CodeTree] = {

  if(trees.length < 2) trees
  else isortForTrees(trees.+:(new Fork(trees.head, trees.tail.head, chars(trees.head).:::(chars(trees.tail.head)), weight(trees.head) + weight(trees.tail.head)))) 

  def isortForTrees(myList: List[CodeTree]): List[CodeTree] = {
    if(myList.isEmpty) Nil
    else insertForTrees(myList.head, isortForTrees(myList.tail))
  }

  def insertForTrees(toBeInserted: CodeTree, lisToBe: List[CodeTree]): List[CodeTree] = {
    if(lisToBe.isEmpty || weight(toBeInserted) < weight(lisToBe.head)) toBeInserted :: lisToBe
    else lisToBe.head :: insertForTrees(toBeInserted, lisToBe.tail)
  }

}
```

I cannot understand why a Unit would be returned ? Both ends of the if statement return a List[CodeTree]. It probably is a silly mistake that I made but I simply cannot find it. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last expression in your method is a method definition which returns `Unit`. Just move

```
if(trees.length < 2) trees
else isortForTrees(trees.+:(new Fork(trees.head, trees.tail.head, chars(trees.head).:::(chars(trees.tail.head)), weight(trees.head) + weight(trees.tail.head))))
```

to the bottom of the method and it should work.